# Transfer non appstore app from iOS Developer Program to iOS Enterprise Program

Tags: ios, ad-hoc-distribution, iphone-developer-program, app-id, in-house-distribution

My client's cooperate app is currently distributed via ad-hoc distribution using iOS developer program and now the client has purchased an iOS enterprise developer program to distribute this application via In-House distribution because of the limitation.

The problem occurred when migrating from developer program to enterprise program. Since App-ID is unique across the accounts, I’m unable to create a identical app-id in the enterprise program.To my knowledge I'm left with two options.

1. Delete the app-id from the developer program and use it on the
   enterprise program to facilitate In-house distribution.
2. Use a separate App-id for the to facilitate In-house distribution

The problem is OTA updates are send via OTA web links and second approach will install a separate identical app.

The question is if I use the first approach will the existing installed app get replaced successful via OTA link since it has the same app-id?

Comment: Any suggestions on this?

Answer (score 0):

Went with option 1.

Option 1 :Delete the app-id from the developer program and use it on the enterprise program to facilitate In-house distribution.

Migrated from developer program to enterprise program using the same app id. Used web url OTA distribution and iTunes sync to update/ install the app. Had no issues with this approach.